# How to get new URL on another tab and then work on it?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

**Test scenario**:

1. Register your account with URL "www.xyz.com"
2. Verify registration success message.
3. Now want to open another tab and get another new URL say "http://www.gmail.com/" for activate the registration by clicking on activate link.

Currently I am able to open another tab but in these not able to get Gmail url. Also, I am working with keyword driven framework.

So, can anyone help me for resolving it?

**Condition in method**:

```
    if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase("urlOnNewTab")){
                    temp.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"t");
                    ArrayList<String> tab = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
                    driver.switchTo().window(tab.get(1));

                    /*String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN); 
                    temp.sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);*/

                    driver.get(value);

                    if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("SendKey")) {
                        temp.sendKeys(value);
                    }

                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click")) {
                        temp.click();
                    }
                    if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Verify")) {
                        System.out.println("Verify--->" + temp);
                        temp.isDisplayed();
                    }
                }


public WebElement getElement(String locator, String objectName)
            throws Exception {
        WebElement temp = null;

        System.out.println("Locator-->" + locator);
        if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.id(objectName));

        } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(objectName));
            System.out.println("xpath temp ----->" + temp);
        } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.name(objectName));
        }else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("linkText")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.linkText(objectName));
        }else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("cssSelector")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(objectName));
        }

        return temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get any feedback from folks but I have tried below code and it work for me as per my question.

**Code:**

```
 if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase("urlOnNewTab")){
                    temp.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"t");
                    driver.get(value);
                    if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("SendKey")) {
                        temp.sendKeys(value);
                    }

                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click")) {
                        temp.click();
                    }
                    if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Verify")) {
                        System.out.println("Verify--->" + temp);
                        temp.isDisplayed();
                    }
                }

    public WebElement getElement(String locator, String objectName)
                throws Exception {
            WebElement temp = null;

            System.out.println("Locator-->" + locator);
            if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
                temp = driver.findElement(By.id(objectName));

            } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")) {
                temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(objectName));
                System.out.println("xpath temp ----->" + temp);
            } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                temp = driver.findElement(By.name(objectName));
            }else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("cssSelector")) {
                temp = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(objectName));
            }

            return temp;
```